RealityKit HasTransform.position throws a runtime exception
I am working on a React Native app, specifically on the iOS native module with RealityKit.
An apparently unexplainable error keeps happening at runtime, as you can see from the following image:

When I try to retrieve the position of my AnchorEntity relative to the world space (so using relativeTo: nil), it triggers a runtime exception during some of its internal calls:
CoreRE: re::BucketArray<unsigned short*, 32ul>::operator[](unsigned long) + 204
As you can see from the code, my AnchorEntity is not null as there is a guard check.
I also tried to move that code into an objective c static function in order to use @try @catch and catch runtime exceptions, to later realise that RealityKit is not compatible with ObjectiveC.
Do you have any idea/suggestion on how to fix it/prevent it?
